# Traversing to a hidden input element and getting its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table element that is loaded by jQuery and have a hidden input element on each row of my table and a button to open a pop up.

My problem is that when I try to get the value of hidden input when the button is clicked, I am not getting the value and it says `undefined` (I have used a jQuery function to get the value in click event of the button)

```
// function to get the hidden input value
$(document).on("click", '#registerhere', function(event) {                 
  var id = $(this).find('#gameid').val();
  console.log(id);
  alert(id);
  $colinforeg = $('#exampleModal');
  $colinforeg.modal('show');
});

// ajax function to load the table
$.ajax({
  url: 'allevents.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'post',   
  success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      console.log(item[0]);
      var events = '<tr>';
      events += '<td>'+item[1]+'</td>';
      events += '<td>'+item[4]+'</td>';
      events += '<td>'+item[5]+'</td>';
      events += '<td>'+item[6]+'</td>';
      events += '<td>'+item[2]+'</td>';
      events += '<td>';
      events += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="registerhere"> Register Here';
      events += '</button>';
      events += '<input type="hidden" id="gameid" value="'+item[0]+'">';
      events += '</td>';
      events += '</tr>';
      $('#events').append(events);
    });
  },
```

Comment: Remember that IDs should be unique - you're applying the same ID to each input element.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are repeating the same `id` attributes in each appended row which is invalid. If you want to group common elements use classes instead.

With regard to the DOM traversal issues, note that the `#gameid` element isn't a child of the `button`, so `find()` isn't going to work there. You could instead get the `closest('tr')` and use `find()` from there:

```js
// function to get the hidden input value
$(document).on("click", '.registerhere', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.gameid').val();
  console.log(id);

  // work with your modal here...
});

// ajax function to load the table
var events = '<tr>';
events += '<td>';
events += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary registerhere">Register Here</button>';
events += '<input type="hidden" class="gameid" value="foo">';
events += '</td>';
events += '</tr>';
$('#events').append(events);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="events"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped